# Creating users (with no registration) using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I want to be able to create users and save them to the database but Devise doesn't pass the request to the database, and doesn't return any error.

```
alice = User.new
alice.name = "Alice"
alice.save!
```

alice gets saved successfully, just not in the database.

I can do `User.find(alice.id)` and it returns data as long as I'm in the same session.

Comment: Go to rails console and try `User.last` and see if it returns the record of the last user you had added. If it returns the expected object then you might have wrong database configuration in the application. Post the `database.yml` code in that case.

Comment: You are right when I search using `User.last` or `User.where(name: "alice")` I don't get anything. 

My configuration is good, because I already have a working registration, and a working application, insert in any table, just not users which Devise controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have this problem, I found that Devise enforces email even when setting

```
email_required?
    false
end
```

so even hitting `save!` will not raise an error.

Therefore the only way i found is to create a fake email, using something like this

```
"guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@anyemail.com"
```

then assign a `self.role = guest`, so the account would be easily identified.

I hope this helps